# Modified PowerShell DiffPatch script cannot write data properly

Tags: powershell, diff, patch

yesterday I decided to test if it's possible to rewrite [this script](https://github.com/belane/PS-BinDiff/blob/master/PS-BinDiff.ps1) into one file. This is my version (short version without checksum verification):

```
param (
  [string]$OriginalFile,
  [string]$PatchFile
)

## FILE DETAILS
$OriginalFile = Resolve-Path $OriginalFile;
$original = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($OriginalFile);

$patched = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($PatchFile);

## DIFFERENCES
$changes = @();
for($byte=0;$byte -le  $original.Length; $byte++) {
    if($original[$byte] -ne $patched[$byte]) {
        $changes += ,@($byte,$original[$byte],$patched[$byte]);
        }
    }

## GENERATE PATCH
$changes = $changes | % { ($($_[0]),$($_[2])); }
$changes += 0;

## BACKUP FILE
Copy-Item -Path $OriginalFile -Destination ($OriginalFile + ".bak");

## READ FILE
$binary = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($OriginalFile);
$patch_bin = $OriginalFile;

## PATCH FILE
$byte_change = 0;
for($byte=0;$byte -lt  $binary.Length; $byte++) {
    if($byte -eq $changes[$byte_change][0]) {
        ## Write-Output "$('{0:X8}' -f $changes[$byte_change][0])  $('{0:X2}' -f $changes[$byte_change][1])";
        $binary[$byte] = $changes[$byte_change][1];
        $byte_change++;
        if($byte_change -eq $changes.Length-1) { break; }
        }
    }

## WRITE FILE
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($patch_bin, $binary);
```

The original script successfully managed to patch a text file A with content '001' to have content '002' from text file B, while my version writes only '00 ' (empty space after second zero). Any ideas where's the problem because I'm playing with PowerShell for the first time?

Comment: That's a lot of code. Please consider providing a [mcve].

Comment: This "a lot of code" is the whole code minus the ##GENERATE PATCH section